# Return boolean true value if object contains true key, not return the value

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I'm really stuck on how to return a simple true/false IF my object contains a key with a true value. I do *not* want to return the key or value itself, just an assertion that it does contain a true value.

E.g

```
var fruits = { apples: false, oranges: true, bananas: true }
```

There's a true value in this object. I don't care which one is true... I just want to be able to return `true` because there is a true value.

My current solution returns `["oranges", "bananas"]` not `true`

```
Object.keys(fruits).filter(function(key) {
    return !!fruits[key]
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Giuseppe Leo's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63828785/6243352), you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (keys aren't important here) to produce an array of the object's values to call [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on:

```js
const fruits = {apples: false, oranges: true, bananas: true};
console.log(Object.values(fruits).includes(true));

// test the sad path
console.log(Object.values({foo: false, bar: 42}).includes(true));
```

If [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is permitted but `Object.values` and `includes` aren't, you can use something like [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var fruits = {apples: false, oranges: true, bananas: true};
console.log(Object.keys(fruits).reduce((a, e) => a || fruits[e] === true, false));
```

If you don't have access to *anything* (or don't like that the `reduce` approach above doesn't short-circuit), you can always write a function to iterate through the keys to find a particular target value (to keep the function reusable for other targets than `true`):

```js
function containsValue(obj, target) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === target) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

var fruits = {apples: false, oranges: true, bananas: true};
console.log(containsValue(fruits, true));
```

Comment: What would be the non ES6 version of this without the fat arrow function?

Comment: `Object.values(fruits).some(function (e) { return e === true; });`

Comment: Just realised that I cannot use Object.values. If I try to use `.map()` the result is returning the values again not boolean

Comment: Can you use `Object.keys()`? I don't follow what you mean with `map`.

Comment: Yes `object.keys` is fine but `.value` and `.some` are not

Answer (score 2):

As you want to know if any of the values is `true`:

```js
Object.values(fruits).includes(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var fruits = { apples: false, oranges: true }
var r = Object.keys(fruits).some(function(key) {
    return !!fruits[key]
})
console.log(r);
```

Though, instead of `Object.keys()`, it is better to use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to iterate the objects *value* directly:

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
var fruits = { apples: false, oranges: true }
var r = Object.values(fruits).some(f => f)
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `Boolean` as callback for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const has = o => Object.values(o).some(Boolean);

var a = {},
    b = { oranges: true, apples : false },
    c = { oranges: false, apples : false };

[a, b, c].forEach(o => console.log(has(o)));
```